# Advantage of running Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 instead of Windows XP

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp

Is there any advantage of running Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 instead of Windows XP?

Comment: You mean besides the cool factor?

Comment: Yes. Cool factor is not an argument for our admins, who prefer heterogeneous environment (read: windows xp). Important factors to me are: stability, speed, features...

Comment: But that also happens to be the value arguments. Admins still running Windows XP are clueless, and shouldn't be in charge of developer machines!

Comment: @Claus:  Big enterprises tend to introduce new versions of Windows on new computers, which means the changeover is usually spaced over three to five years.  Moreover, they generally don't start until the new version has been out for a while and they've extensively tested it.  Assuming they had the wisdom to skip Vista on the desktop, most large enterprises will be XP-free by about 2013 or 2014.  There are good reasons to proceed this way, and not to continually try to be at the cutting edge.

Comment: No, there were good reasons for doing it 10-15 years ago. The world moved on, and stubborn admins living in the '90s are slowing everything down. Also a heterogeneous environment is a absolutely no-go for desktop software developers. It might make sense for Carol the secretary, who only uses Outlook and Internet Explorer, but not for everybody else. Just because most enterprise companies works as a slow monster, doesn't justify it in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the [difference between WPF on XP and Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2007/01/05/comparing-wpf-on-windows-vista-v-windows-xp.aspx) (Aero), as one of the arguments. Beyond that, insert all generic improvements in Windows for the last decade, and so on...

Edit: To clarify, Visual Studio 2010 uses WPF, so you get a much faster and stable IDE by using it on Vista/Windows 7.

Answer (score 8):

First, Windows 7 has goodies to offer you. I am more productive on Windows 7. And Visual Studio 2010 (unlike 2008 and earlier) is Windows 7 aware. I get nice jumplists to make it easier to get to recent projects, for example. It also makes it possible to install Visual Studio extensions like [the one I blogged](http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/VisualStudioAddinForWindows7TaskbarExtras.aspx) that adds a compiler progress bar as an overlay on your taskbar icon, so you can minimize VS during a slow build and know how it's doing.

Second, moving your prime machine to 7 is likely to help your users. Many developers have been caught off balance the first time their application is deployed to a machine on which they are not an admin. Developing on Windows 7 is one way to be sure your application works with UAC, and works on an XP machine being run by a non-admin (if you ever meet one.) Getting in the habit of using Windows 7 features yourself will encourage you to hook them into your application. Staying on XP yourself increases the tendency that you will deliver an XP application people can kinda sorta mostly use on Windows 7, rather than a Windows 7 application.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, I think it's better to develop on your target platform. So if you develop **for** Windows 7, develop **on** Win7. If you develop **for** XP, I would suggest developing **on** XP.

Everything else is a matter of taste. Yes, there are many developers who  love Win7 and can't imagine going back to the ancient XP. On the other hand, there are still quite a few folks around who consider XP to be the more mature Windows, and won't consider switching before Win7 SP2 is out.

Take your pick...

Comment: That's rather narrow. If you target multiple platforms, you should test on all of them (Virtual Machines make it easy). However, there's quite the difference in terms of available APIs (Windows 7 jumpstart features, etc), and visual appearances of WPF/Silverlight based applications. 

So it's definitively not just a matter of taste.

Comment: @Claus: You are absolutely right about testing on all target platforms! But my point is that by developing on your (main) target platform, you get the benefit of early testing (while you develop) on that platform, as opposed to developing and finding out later during testing that things work a little different than they do on your dev system.  
And yes, there may be more to it than just taste... it's just that having used VS on bot XP and 7, I find the differences from a user's perspective to be rather small, YMMV of course.

Comment: I understand your point and agree with that. My target platform is ASP.NET, so I don't think this is applicable here (unless I consider putting the Windows Server on my laptop).

Answer (score 3):

I guess it also depends on what is your target, if you do application development (read WPF/Windows Forms) then, like it has already been said, it will need to be tested on multiple platforms so doesn't make *much* difference. However, if you are doing web application development then you should target the specific IIS version you are going to deploy to. This has become easier with the launch of IIS Express, however if targeting IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2 then run Windows 7 :-)

In my experience, Windows 2008 R2 running as a workstation is pretty good, but has lack of support for some DVD-RW drives and graphics cards can be a little unstable so stick with Windows 7 :-)

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

The killer argument is: VS 2010 is way more stable on Win7 than it is on XP. I have both configurations running, and depending on what I'm exactly doing, VS crashes about every 30 minutes on XP, whereas it seldomly crashes on Win7.

This is largely caused by the fact that VS 2010 uses Windows Presentation Foundation, which was not at all on the scene when XP was designed.

But overall, I experienced VS 2010 being much more unstable than 2008 anyway as for now. I pray for SP1 every single day ;-)...

EDIT:
I don't think it is helpful to care about the target platform in the first place. To me, it's much more important to have a reliable everyday working environment.

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

If you using Windows XP you do not experience the full feature set of WPF and Window 7's transparency. It is a another matter that your system can play much faster than in Windows 7.

Window 7 gives you a full feeling of all features for full enjoyment of the development on Window 7.

Visual Studio is developed upon WPF so working with current technologies is much better than working with the old version.

I myself use Visual Studio on Window 7 but use the classic mode which give me the feeling of Window XP classic.